# How to enable partial matching in Django Haystack with Xapian

Tags: django, search, partial, django-haystack, xapian

I have downloaded xapian-core and xapian-bindings and installed them via the following commands

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/virtualenv
./configure --prefix=/path/to/virtualenv --with-python

pip install django-haystack xapian-haystack
```

So far I have the search working with whole word matching but cannot figure out how to enable partial word matching. I even tried with ngram fields and still no luck. I have tried searching on google and cannot find any clear instructions so hopefully someone here can help me out.